# bootstrap check box is not working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="ui-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="" checked="" id="checkAll" data-cacheval="true">
</div>
```

```js
$('#checkAll').click(function () {
    $('.ui-checkbox input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

My code is working fine , but below code same code is not working if i am adding label in the html

```html
<div class="ui-checkbox"><label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on">&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" class="checkSingle" value="" checked="" id="checkItem-3913238"></div>
```

How can i access label in js ?

below is my full code

```html
<table class="table display table-striped bulk-assign-tbl" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
     <th><label><input type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAll" checked>&nbsp;</label></th>
     <th>Item Name</th>
   </tr>
  <?php foreach ($item_data as $key => $val): ?><tr>

   <td><label id="checkAllLabel"><input type="checkbox" class="checkSingle" value="" checked id ="checkItem-<?= $val['chkoiid'] ?>">&nbsp;</label></td>
      <td> <?php echo $val['name']; ?> </td>
    </tr>                            
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
```

```js
 $('#checkAll,#checkAllLabel').click(function () {
         $('.ui-checkbox input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
 });
  $(".checkSingle").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var isAllChecked = 0;
  $(".checkSingle").each(function () {
            if (!this.checked)
                isAllChecked = 1;
     });

 if (isAllChecked == 0) {
      $("#checkAll").prop("checked", true);
       }
     } else {
        $("#checkAll").prop("checked", false);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Your logic seems fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/gkn7hexf/. Please edit the question to show the *actual* issue.

Comment: Your full code seems to be missing an opening `tr` tag in your loop...

Comment: I would suggest you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) which demonstrates the problem happening. Then ideally paste that code directly in your question. This PHP code is not useful as we cannot run it to identify your exact problem

Comment: okay i will create

Comment: main problem is i want to access the jquery code with label , it will solve my problem , because without label everything working fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. 
https://jsfiddle.net/h781y2pv/

you have missed `for` attribute for the label, added that now.

```
 <label for="checkAll" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-on">Click me</label>
```

If you want to access the label in JS. you can access it like any other element. `$('ui-checkbox label')` or give a class or Id to it and `$('.ui-checkbox-label')` assuming class name added is "ui-checkbox-label"